# Regex: Add * before and after words Followed by ;

Tags: windows, notepad++

I have some words followed by `;` or `(space);`

For exemple:

```
mother_is_home;
 I love hoping;
James;
Cupidon is magic ;
```

I want to use some regex to get the following, without any space before and after words:

```
*mother_is_home*;
*I love hoping*;
*James*;
*Cupidon is magic*;
```

Any case, I made a regex, but is not very good. I still have problem with empth space before and after words

Find: `(\w+)(.*?);`

Replace by: `*${1}${2}*;`

Answer (score 1):

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>H</kbd>
- Find what: `^\h*(.+?)\h*;$`
- Replace with: `*$1*;`
- <kbd>Replace all</kbd>

**Explanation:**

```
^       : begining of line
\h*     : 0 or more horizontal spaces
(.+?)   : group 1, 1 or more any character, not greedy
\h*     : 0 or more horizontal spaces
;       : semi colon
$       : end of line
```

- DO NOT CHECK `. matches newline`

**Replacement:**

```
*$1*;
```

**Result for given example:**

```
*mother_is_home*;
*I love hoping*;
*James*;
*Cupidon is magic*;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the following regex to match the string:

```
( *)?(\w+)(.*);
```

And to replace you would use the following:

```
*${2}${3}*;
```

---

The regex that worked for Just Me was the following:

```
( *)?(\w+)(\s*);
```

A good place to practice regular expressions is http://regexr.com/.

Comment: good in a case, but if i have in the same line `word1; word2;word3; word4 ;` will not work :) Must be something with `\s`

Comment: What is the expected output in the scenario `word1; word2;word3; word4 ;`?  Another possibility would be to use `( *)?(\w+)(\s*);` and replace using `*${2}*;`

Comment: thank you, user8431088, you have right with `(\s*)`  I use it on my regex, and now works fine.

Comment: Glad to hear it! Could you please accept the answer as well?

Answer (score 0):

Search: `(\s)*(\w+)(.*?)(\s)*;`

Replace By:  `*${2}${3}*;`

Comment: Why using such number of groups? A single one is enough, see my answer.